# how to push elements in between mongodb aggregate query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

i have a document like this

```
[
  {
    "key": "key1",
    "shops": [
      {
        "shopId": "S1",
        "ShopName": "SN1"
      },
      {
        "shopId": "S2",
        "ShopName": "SN2"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

i need to write an aggerate query and i have to push some static elements in an array

i tried like below

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "key": "key1"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      "shops": {
        $push: {
          "shopId": "S3",
          "ShopName": "SN3"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": {
      "path": "$shops"
    }
  }
])
```

my aim is to add new element in 'shops' array and unwind the document. excepted result should look like below

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "key": "key1",
    "shops": {
      "ShopName": "SN1",
      "shopId": "S1"
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "key": "key1",
    "shops": {
      "ShopName": "SN2",
      "shopId": "S2"
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "key": "key1",
    "shops": {
      "ShopName": "SN3",
      "shopId": "S3"
    }
  }
]
```

Can you please help me out. Thank you in advance

Comment: Use `$concatArrays` (you dont need the `$group` stage - instead `$addFields`).

Answer (score 0):

Check this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lE0qolkyEvc).

My method is adding a temporary field `withStatic` which is a concat of `shops` and static elements, then using `$unwind` to deconstruct it, reassigning `shops` to deconstructed item and finally removing `withStatic` from result.